# Why can a struct be passed as an interface to a function?

Tags: go

I have some [example code](https://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go/) that takes an interface as an input as below.

```golang
type RouteGuideServer interface {
        ...
}

func RegisterRouteGuideServer(s *grpc.Server, srv RouteGuideServer) {
    s.RegisterService(&_RouteGuide_serviceDesc, srv)
}
```

That is all fine and good, but then when implementing this server we have the following code which gives a struct (that implements the interface) to the function as below.

```golang
type routeGuideServer struct {
        ...
}

...

pb.RegisterRouteGuideServer(grpcServer, &routeGuideServer{})
```

I would expect that an error is thrown when given the wrong type.. why does this work? I feel that this shouldn't work?

I would appriciate any feedback, Thanks!

Comment: Does `*routeGuideServer` implement `RouteGuideServer`? If so, then the code is correct and working as intended.

Comment: yes, but why.. Its a `struct` not an `interface` I would expect a type error to be thrown.. It bothers me that it doesn't seem to be logically sound.

Comment: See https://tour.golang.org/methods/1 ff. And of course the language spec. Can you explain where your feeling about a missing type error are based on?

Comment: I think I feel this way because logically speaking type `struct` is not type `interface` and I have never transformed it into one.. so it shouldn't be able to be used as `interface`

Comment: type `struct` is not type `interface`, that's true. But that specific struct type in question **implements** (or satisfies) the specific interface type and therefore can be used whereever that interface type is expected. In Go interfaces are implemented **implicitly**, that means you don't have to ever say that struct `S` implements interface `I`. If struct `S` implements all of the methods that the interface `I` defines in its method set then `S` automatically implements `I`.

Comment: @mkopriva I understand! I am not going to say its not confusing why it is implemented in that way, but I do understand.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `interface` defines a set of methods. Any type that has those methods "implements" that interface.

In your case, you have a struct type implementing all the methods of an interface. That means values of that struct type can be used wherever such an interface is needed. When you pass a struct value to a function like you did, the complier will check if the value implements all the functions of the interface, and if it does, send the value as an interface to the function. Outside the function you have your struct value, but inside the function, you can only see the functions of that interface. You can, however, make a type assertion and recover the value of that interface:

```
func (f interfaceType) {
   if k, ok := f.(myType); ok {
      // Here, k is the value of the interface, which is of type "myType"
   }
```

Comment: so it implicitly transforms my struct into an interface without my intervention? do you know where I can read about this?

Comment: It doesn't "transform" the value. It passes the value to the function as an interface. As I said above, you can still get the underlying value from the interface. This  is similar to assigning an interface value to a struct. For instance, you can to this: var i RouteGuideServerInterface = &routeGuideServer{}. Here, i is an interface whose value is a struct. You can find a lot of resources by searching for "go interfaces", one is: https://gobyexample.com/interfaces

Comment: @bserdar Thank you for the explaination, and `var i RouteGuideServerInterface = &routeGuideServer{}` is exactly what I would expect would be required to pass to the function.  Not having to do this seems odd.. but I suppose if the `struct` is implementing an `interface`, then in the background its recognized as a type `interface` though being a `struct`.. quite confusing

Comment: Search for "duck typing". There are lots of resources out there explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

This works because `*routeGuideServer` implements `RouteGuideServer`.
If wrongType doesn't implement `RouteGuideServer`, you'll get an error:

> wrongType does not implement RouteGuideServer(missing "some" method)

[example](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces)

Comment: so the `struct` would automatically be interpreted as the `interface` provided that it has the same methods.. confusing but I suppose if it works.